# Can i add my code and ask several Qs on each part of it? Or should i discect them into seperate smaller Qs and add each alone?

Tags: discussion

I wrote a whole code for the first time. It's a bit long (at least for me), and i don't know if is can just paste the whole code and ask Qs on each part of it or separate the code into many smaller Qs and all them all.
Please advise.

Comment: Each question should be complete. Asking them by-parts doesn't make sense. You can use pastebin to paste your code and include that link in your question, in case your code is breaching the character limit :)

Comment: Ok, i thought so, but i also thought that it is not allowed since it has several Qs and might confuse those who are looking for information. The previous answer kind of confirmed this. So you are saying that yes it is allowed to post my whole code and ask several Qs about it in Stack Overflow in the same post, right?

Comment: Yes, If those questions all inter-related very closely.  anyways, why not ask one away and let the community decide :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions about code typically belong on Stack Overflow. You need to ask a clear question about one issue in a question, not paste a lot of code.